# Delete entire Row from Table in database and display all data in table(i.e., auto update the table in same page)

Tags: java, html, database, jsp, derby

In table 10 rows are there..selected data has to delete (using check box) and display all the content in table....Here newsid in JSP file is auto incremented value....

This is DeleteSuccess.java File

```
  public class DeleteSuccess extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    HttpSession session=request.getSession();  

    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDataBase","root","root");

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("delete from ROOT.NEWSTABLE where newsid='" + (* here what i have 2 write *) +"'");
        int i=  ps.executeUpdate();



        PreparedStatement pss = con.prepareStatement("select NEWSID,NEWS from ROOT.NEWSTABLE");
        ResultSet rs =pss.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<News> listnewsobj = new ArrayList<News>();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            News obj=new News();
            obj.setNewsId(rs.getInt(1));
            obj.setNews(rs.getString(2));
            listnewsobj.add(obj); 
        }


        session.setAttribute("listnewskey",listnewsobj);
        System.out.println(listnewsobj);
        if (i > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Venkatesh");
            //out.print("You are successfully registered...");
            //RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.html");
         //   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("JSP/AddNews.jsp");
          //  rd.include(request, response);
             response.sendRedirect("JSP/AddNews.jsp");
        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        System.out.println(e2);
    }

    out.close();
}
```

}

This is JSP file

```
        <form method="post" action="../newsdelete">
         <fieldset class="rt">
            <legend> <b> Manage News </b> </legend>

         <table>
         <tr>
            <th>News Id</th>
            <th>News Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
         </tr>


    <c:forEach items="${listnewskey}" var="listnews">
    <tr>    

        <td class="first_col">${listnews.newsId}</td>
        <td>${listnews.news}</td>  

        <td class="third_col">
<input id="" type="checkbox" name="check" value="action"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label>
        </td>

    </tr>
    </c:forEach>  


    </table>
            <div> <br><input  type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete"></div>
 </fieldset>


</form>
```

This is web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Delete</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.venkatesh.DeleteSuccess</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Delete</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/newsdelete</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Can anyone tell me how to delete the row which is checked and automatically display the information from the table in same JSP file which i have written the table in Loop...

Comment: To delete a row you execute a SQL `delete` statement. To display information from a table you execute a SQL `select` statement, and then loop through the `ResultSet` that is returned.

Comment: I have tried all those which are given in above code..
when i select checkbox and press delete button no response is there..what is the logic behind selected checkbox through which that row has to be delete..??

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me if you're trying to learn (a) how to write SQL, or if you're trying to learn (b) how to use the JDBC API, or if you're trying to learn (c) how to write JSPs. It's hard to learn all three of those things at once, so you might try first learning one, then the next, then the next, then finally combine all three.

Comment: i am asking how to delete entire row in the database once checkbox is clicked.. i am confused to trace checkbox connection to database through code..